# Values not being pushed back into vector while reading from a file

Tags: c++, c++11

My `.txt` file has values like:

```
36.68
36.64
36.66
36.66
```

& I'm reading values using the following code:

```
ifstream ifs;
ifs.open("F:/test_files/IBM_prices.txt");
if (!ifs) { cerr << "cannot open prices file"; };

double price;

while (ifs >> price) {

    cout << price << endl;                             //for debugging
    vector <double>v;
    v.push_back(price);
    cout << "vector size is" << v.size() << endl;      //for debugging

}
```

When I run the code, vector keeps showing size as `1`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

You have a brand-new `v` for every iteration; it's a local object defined inside the loop block.

Move the definition out of the loop.

```
vector<double> v;
while (ifs >> price) {

    cout << price << endl;                             //for debugging
    v.push_back(price);
    cout << "vector size is" << v.size() << endl;      //for debugging

}
```

Comment: You gun is blazing fast, +1 : )

Answer (score 1):

Your `vector <double>v` is **defined within the `while` loop** and so it is defined **in every iteration**, and its size is always 1. Define it outside the `while` loop and you will have the actual size.

You can have the `cout` inside the `while` and you can see how the size of the `vector` increments with every `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare vector outside the {} boundaries of while.
When you do it like you wrote, you create new vector for every iteration of cycle, that recieves one element and dies at the end.

```
vector <double>v;
while (ifs >> price) {...
```